# WCF: Use a Message Contract to make a Soap Header

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wcf

I need to add a soap header to my web service.  I plan to use this to validate my clients (Windows Mobile Devices).

I found this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rog_21/soapheaders05172007120046PM/soapheaders.aspx

Which is exactly what I want to do.  But it is not written for WCF.

I have done some research and I seem to be paralyzed by the [number](http://paulpierce.co.uk/?p=19) [of](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToUse&referringTitle=Home) [options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx).

I basically want to add a simple header to my soap object that will be a user name and password.  The client does not use WCF, so the soap header needs to just be a normal soap header.

Any Sample code or shoves in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than define a DataContract, use MessageContract

```
[MessageContract]
public class YourMessageType
{
  // This is in the SOAP Header
  [MessageHeader] public string UserName {get;set;}
  [MessageHeader] public string Password {get;set;}

  // This is in the SOAP body
  [MessageBodyMember] public string OtherData {get;set;}
  ...
}
```

Comment: So, MessageContract is an either or with DataContract?  I have a lot of DataContracts already.  Do I just convert them to Message contract and say where everything goes?  (I hope it is just that simple!)

Comment: Could I just set the OtherData to be the DataContract?  (Is that poor design?)

Comment: @Vaccano, yes you can either use DataContracts or go for the finer graned control over the message structure using MessageContracts. You should be able to just convert to using MessageContracts.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use UsernameToken in SOAP header if you have to pass only username paaword and use custom  UserNamePasswordValidator as a pluggable service behaviour.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702565.aspx